# Connecting my android application (Android studio) with Odoo 9

Tags: android, odoo-9

I am new with the erp Odoo 9 , and i had a problem conneting my android application to my server where i installed Odoo 9 , any help how to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://github.com/timroes/aXMLRPC) : Java XML-RPC client for the use with Android.

Odoo has an xmlrpc interface so you can use its [webservice](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/api_integration.html).

Comment: I used the java code in the Odoo Web service and i get these errors : can't access XmlRpcHttpRequstConfig,XmlRpcHttpRequstConfigImpl and XmlRpcHttpController while running my Project !! any help @Mraimou ???